# Put DropShadowEffect below neighboring disabled elements

Tags: wpf, dropshadoweffect

I have several Borders in a Grid, each has a DropShadowEffect. When a Border is disabled (`IsEnabled = false`), the DropShadowEffect of the neighboring Borders is *above* it, thus visible and weird looking.

[image: DropShadowEffect above disabled Borders]

This is even though I explicitely set the `Panel.ZIndex` such that there shouldn't be. It doesn't even matter how I sort the Borders.

When the buttons are enabled, everything is fine.